# Python appending to file

Tags: python

```
while True:
    item = str(raw_input('Please enter the name of your item: '))
    f = open('sample.txt', 'a')
    f.write(item + '\n')
    f.close()
```

My goal is to get this to keep adding items to a text document, sample.txt. However, each time I run the program, the old data that was appended is written over... How to fix? To clarify, I want a running list in a text document of each item that is entered.   Thanks!

Comment: that code should work as you expect

Answer (score 4):

```
with open('sample.txt', 'a') as f:
    while True:
        item = raw_input('Please enter the name of your item: ')
        if item == '':
            break
        f.write(item + '\n')
```

Key points:

- Write the item to the file, not the string 'item'
- Close the file *outside* the while loop
- Provide a 'sentinel' object to break out of the loop cleanly (in this case, hit enter without typing anything)

Answer (score 0):

You're writing the string `'item'`, not the value of the variable `item`.  Change your write call to `f.write(item + '\n')`

Comment: While I was typing the answer, you seem to have realized that mistake.  The code now posted works fine for me.